# Support additional fields as tags for Tumblr search...

Tags: c#, search, tumblr

I am trying to find a way to add the submission of someone's name to the search function. I need to send the name as a tag, but the issue is on the display end.

You can see the site here - **http://southu.tumblr.com/** You will need a password - **test123**

The tag is displayed above the video. The current tags are "**Commitment**" and "**Sacrifice**". The name is separate so it can be displayed in a different spot. Tumblr doesn't inherently allow for defining between different tags on the display side.

Basically, I need to support both fields as tags, but not display the name in the tag display (above the video)

Here is the C# from the VideoSubmissionController.cs file.

```
        // Posts the video submission using the TumblrApi.
    private void SendToTumblr(VideoSubmission videoSubmission)
    {
        string consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TumblrConsumerKey");
        string consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TumblrConsmerSecret");
        string oauthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TumblrOauthTokenKey");
        string oauthVerifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TumblrOauthTokenSecret");

        Token token = new Token(oauthToken, oauthVerifier);
        var client_factory = new TumblrClientFactory();
        using (var client = client_factory.Create<TumblrClient>(consumerKey, consumerSecret, token))
        {
            //string body = "This post was created through the api";
            //string title = "Testing API Push";
            string[] tags = new string[] { videoSubmission.Question.QuestionText };

            //create the data for a text post: use PostData.CreateText
            var postData = PostData.CreateVideo(videoSubmission.VideoUrl, videoSubmission.Name, tags);

            //create the post: pass the name of the blog where to post to
            var postTask = client.CreatePostAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TumblrUrl"), postData);
            postTask.Wait();
            var postResult = postTask.Result;
            videoSubmission.TumblrId = postResult.PostId.ToString();
            db.Entry(videoSubmission).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want to show on the frontend? I imagine its possible to *hide* certains tags with CSS3 selectors.

Comment: This is the best I can do as far as an example. **[http://prntscr.com/5v7z0s](http://prntscr.com/5v7z0s)**

Comment: (cont'd)

Basically, I want the name to be searchable, but in order to do that, it has to be a tag. But, if it's a tag, it will display the name in the tag field. Looking for a way to identify the name as a tag, but not have it display. Almost like making it tag2, but keep the display hidden. Make more sense?

Comment: A little. When you say *tag field*? What do you mean exactly? The word `sacrifice`? If you make them anchors linking to the actually tagged page `tagged/sacrifice` its possible to hide them with CSS3 selectors.

Comment: When someone submits a video to this site, they are able to select one of 5 tags, so the videos can be categorized. *Sacrifice* and *Commitment* are what you see on the page.

Comment: Which out of `sacrifice` and `commitment` would you like to hide?

Comment: I don't think I'm being clear. I don't want to hide either ***sacrifice*** or ***commitment***. I want to carry the name as an additional tag, but I don't want the name to display in the tag field. Unfortunately, this is the way Tumblr's search function works.

Comment: Put an underscore before the tag and it won't display but it will still show up in search.